# window.onbeforeunload not firing

Tags: javascript

I have created a fairly ajax-heavy web app and i am using the `window.onbeforeunload` event to detect if there are unsaved changes by the user and prevent her from navigating away from the page. The code is loaded by my init function and it used to work on all browsers that support the event. However, suddenly the onbeforeunload event stopped firing on every browser for no apparent reason. i am using jquery 1.7.1 and there are a lot of events attached to various elements (either via delegation or directly). Does anyone have a clue what might be the problem here? Here is a code snip:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if($(window).data("confirm") > 0)
        return "You have unsaved changes";
    else
        return null;
  };
});
```

p.s. Even if i completely remove the check from within the callback and always return a string, which should prompt a message every time, it still does not fire. I have checked that my browsers are working correctly with the event with simple pages that bind a callback to it.

Comment: it might be possible that the error is somewhere else, as this code snippet looks fine to me. Perhaps it is firing, but not showing the dialog?

Comment: to 11684: the event is definitely not firing, i tried printing out something to the console and i get nothing. Also i added a breakpoint and tried to debug but again whenever i leave the page it will not pause. The problem is somewhere else i guess but i do not mess with this event anywhere else in the whole page, unless one of the libraries does...hmmm

Comment: Have you tried manually triggering this event (`$(window).trigger('beforeunload');`) and stepping through that to see where it takes you? Some other code might be rewriting your handler silently. Also, why are you binding it like this instead of through `$('window').bind('beforeunload', function() {})` ?

Comment: @DCoder, i had tried triggering the event manually through jquery but i did it after i was doing various other stuff. Your suggestion got me to try it immediately after i bind the callback to it and of course it worked. The thing is, since i don't mess with the event but i use $('#container').delegate() and $('#container').on() quite i bit, could this be rewriting my handler? Cause i have looked at the various libs i use and i didn't find an offender

Comment: @DCoder, i was searching in my lib files for 'onbeforeunload' and couldn't find anything but you got me thinking and i found out that the version of this library http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ that i am using rewrites this event using jquery, i.e. qq.attach(window,"beforeunload",function(b){
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Any string';
};
</script>
```

Comment: the event still does not fire, even i copy paste the code above. I would like to stress that the code that i have showed was working fine for months and it suddenly inexplicably stopped, for all browsers

Comment: I have checked & verified this code, it works fine. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/b7MXZ/)

Comment: Of course it does in general, but it doesn't work for me in the wep app that i have built. Perhaps i should rephrase my question, are there any known reasons that would prevent window.onbeforeunload from firing? As i said, it used to work for me just fine and all of a sudden it stopped (i have added various functionality to the app in the meantime)

Comment: that is my 'somewhere else'. I know you said you don't mess with this event, but javascript can act very strange sometimes. @nvrs

Answer (score 2):

A possible cause for this is using the autocomplete feature of jQuery UI. Versions starting from 1.8.17 set `unbeforeunload`, which disables existing handlers.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12061 claims the bug has been fixed, but in my testing it's still in jQuery UI 1.9.2.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8439 provides a possible workaround.