# onbeforeunload not working

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload

Below is the code snippet that I am using but onbeforeunload event handler is never called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->

<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Submit</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab1.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab4.css">
<!-- LayerSlider styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab5.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab6.css" id="coloroption">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab7.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/themes/ab8.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/ab9.css" id="styleswitcher">

<script src="/Content/themes/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/themes/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/themes/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery with jQuery Easing, and jQuery Transit JS -->
<%--<script src="layerslider/jQuery/jquery-easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script src="layerslider/jQuery/jquery-transit-modified.js"></script>--%>

<!-- LayerSlider from Kreatura Media with Transitions -->

<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/themes/Scripts/combobox/dd.css" />
<script src="/Content/themes/Scripts/combobox/jquery.dd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnCallUnload() {
        debugger;
        var xmlData = "<Root sMethodName='SaveState'>";
        fnSetCommonDataToXMLVariable(xmlData);
        xmlData += "</Root>";

        CallServer(xmlData, "");
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = fnCallUnload;
</script>
</head>
```

I tried onbeforeunload event in the master page and calling a function of content page in the try catch. It does work smoothly there. But this page where I am trying to use onbeforeunload does not require master page. Its a stand alone page in the application. So, I guess there is some minor concept I am not aware of regarding the use of onbeforeunload.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it's too late in the page cycle to even consider calling the server, do it long before user hits their back button or closes tab or shuts down browser or even computer

Comment: @charlietfl I have done this before. Calling a javascript function in onbeforeunload and the call RaiseCallbackEvent fucntion of code behind using callback functionality and it does work. I am confused why it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, however unbeforeunload requires a string to be returned. If not it will not fire due to security reasons.

Add this as last line.

```
return "Do you want to quit?";
```

However this thread blames jQuery as culprit
[window.onbeforeunload not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266623/window-onbeforeunload-not-firing)

change

```
window.onbeforeunload = fnCallUnload;
```

to

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", fnCallUnload, false);
```

Comment: Interesting thing is, same thing works in other pages where Master page is there and the master page contains same amount of JQuery.

Comment: @user2861226 Indeed interesting. Look a the code edit.

Comment: Looks like working but getting some js errors related to ajaxtoolkit when adding this line of code. Thanks anyways, I will investigate and post the reason of those js errors and then mark your post as Answer